# UIScrollView not working properly when adding UILabels to view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, constraints

I am creating my UIScrollView programmatically. When I add all my labels and button to the UIScrollView it won't scroll anymore and I am not able to see anything if it goes past the view. I am new to programmatically creating views and UIScrollViews. I have left out some code such as UILabels because it is repetitive and they all match the stepTwo UILabel.

```
  lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let view = UIScrollView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.contentSize.height = 1200
    return view
}()
 let stepTwo: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()

    let attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Step 2:\n", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 45)])

    attributedTitle.append(NSAttributedString(string: "See Your Doctor", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]))

    label.attributedText = attributedTitle
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    return label
}()
 override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    setupScrollView()
    setupScrollViewLabels()
}
 func setupScrollView(){

     scrollView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 200, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

}
func setupScrollViewLabels(){
    scrollView.addSubview(stepOne)
    scrollView.addSubview(stepOneDetails)
    scrollView.addSubview(reportButton)
    scrollView.addSubview(stepTwo)
    scrollView.addSubview(stepTwoDetails)

    stepOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true

    stepOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

    stepOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    stepOne.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    stepOne.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true


    stepOne.anchor(top: scrollView.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: scrollView.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 0)

    stepOneDetails.anchor(top: stepOne.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 10, width: 0, height: 0)
    reportButton.anchor(top: stepOneDetails.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 30, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 50)

    stepTwo.anchor(top: reportButton.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 25, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 0)

    stepTwoDetails.anchor(top: stepTwo.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 10, width: 0, height: 0)
}
```

Comment: It looks like there's a mix of constraints to the scrollview and the view which could be messing up scrolling since the view doesn't scroll. Also follow this for setting up scroll views with autolayout. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't set the `.contentHeight` of your scroll view. Use auto-layout and constraints, and let the system do the calculation for you.

Second, make sure you have a complete "chain" of constraints from the top to the bottom. Your top element (label) needs to be constrained to the top of the scroll view, and your bottom element (label) needs to be constrained to the bottom of the scroll view. All the other vertical constraints should be from the Bottom of the element above it.

Third, I highly recommend ***not*** using any sort of "constraint convenience" function / extension (e.g. the `.anchor(top: left: bottom: ....)` you're using). At least until you fully understand how constraints work, use this format:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        // stepOne to top + 10 padding and leading/trailing + 20 padding
        stepOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 10.0),
        stepOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
        stepOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),

        // and so on...
    ])
```

Only a *little* more typing, much more readable, and you learn what each constraint is supposed to be doing.

Fourth, while working on your layout, I also recommend setting background colors on views, labels, etc. Makes it so much easier to see the frames and spacing.

So -- here's an example using your posted code as a basis. I made the vertical spacing between elements larger than you had in your code... on an iPhone X there wasn't enough content to scroll. This should do it. Run it on an iPhone 7 (simulator or device) if it still doesn't scroll on a "X". There are lots of comments explaining the constraint setup.

```
class AnotherViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // don't do this... let auto-layout and constraints handle the scrollable area
        // view.contentSize.height = 1200

        //so we can see it
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        return view
    }()

    let stepOne: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        let attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Step 1:\n", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 45)])
        attributedTitle.append(NSAttributedString(string: "This is Step 1", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]))
        label.attributedText = attributedTitle
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        return label
    }()

    let stepOneDetails: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        let attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Step 1 Details:\n", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 45)])
        attributedTitle.append(NSAttributedString(string: "This is Step 1 Details", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]))
        label.attributedText = attributedTitle
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        return label
    }()

    let stepTwo: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        let attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Step 2:\n", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 45)])
        attributedTitle.append(NSAttributedString(string: "See Your Doctor a 2nd time", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]))
        label.attributedText = attributedTitle
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        return label
    }()

    let stepTwoDetails: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        let attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Step 2 Details:\n", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 45)])
        attributedTitle.append(NSAttributedString(string: "This is Step 2 Details", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]))
        label.attributedText = attributedTitle
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        return label
    }()

    let reportButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.setTitle("Report Button", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = .blue
        return b
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        setupScrollView()
        setupScrollViewLabels()
    }

    func setupScrollView(){

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 200.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

    }

    func setupScrollViewLabels(){
        scrollView.addSubview(stepOne)
        scrollView.addSubview(stepOneDetails)
        scrollView.addSubview(reportButton)
        scrollView.addSubview(stepTwo)
        scrollView.addSubview(stepTwoDetails)

        // we're using auto-layout
        reportButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // for each of the labels
        [stepOne, stepOneDetails, stepTwo, stepTwoDetails].forEach {

            // we're using auto-layout
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            // set background colors so we can see the frames of the elements
            $0.backgroundColor = .cyan

        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // stepOne to top + 10 padding and leading/trailing + 20 padding
            stepOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            stepOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stepOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            // stepOneDetails to stepOne + 40 padding and leading/trailing + 20 padding
            stepOneDetails.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stepOne.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            stepOneDetails.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stepOneDetails.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            // reportButton to stepOneDetails + 60 padding and leading/trailing + 20 padding
            reportButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stepOneDetails.bottomAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            reportButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            reportButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            // reportButton height to 50
            reportButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),

            // stepTwo to reportButton + 50 padding and leading/trailing + 20 padding
            stepTwo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reportButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 50.0),
            stepTwo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stepTwo.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            // stepTwoDetails to stepTwo + 40 padding and leading/trailing + 20 padding
            stepTwoDetails.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stepTwo.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            stepTwoDetails.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stepTwoDetails.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            // also must define a width-basis for the scrollable area (the .contentSize),
            //  so use stepOne label, and make it the width of the scrollView minus 40 (20-pts on each side)
            stepOne.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -40.0),

            // and we have to constrain the last element to the bottom of the scrollView
            //  with 10 padding (note: it must be negative)
            stepTwoDetails.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10.0),

            ])

    }

}
```